# Integer increment (++) crashes application

Tags: c

I am trying to write a small program in C but I am stuck trying to increment an `int`.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<string.h>


char * compress(char *input, int size){

    char *inputCopy;
    char compressedString[100];
    snprintf(inputCopy, size, "%s", input);
    int i = 0;
    int counter;
    int j;

    while(i < size){
        counter = 1;
        j = i;
        while (inputCopy[j] == inputCopy[j + 1] && j < size){
            j++;
            printf("same! \n");
            counter++; // When this line is commented out it works.
        }
        if (i != j){
            i = j;
        }else{
            i++;
        }

    }

    return inputCopy;
}

main(){
    char test[10] = "aaaaaaasdd";
    printf("%s \n", compress(test, 10));
    printf("%s", test);

    return 0;
}
```

The `counter++` line for some reason is making my program crash.
I know it is probably something simple, but can someone point out to me why this is not working?

Comment: What is the goal of your pogram?

Comment: The crash is due to the undefined behaviour of `snprintf(inputCopy` with an uninitialized pointer. `char *inputCopy;` has not been initialized.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not allocating data for `snprintf`.  `inputCopy` is uninitialized, so it's probably writing over the memory used by `counter`.  Make sure you allocate the necessary memory.

Unrelated to this crash, but you have a potential for invalid reads (`inputCopy[j + 1]`).  Switch `j < size` to `(j + 1) < size` and move it to the beginning of the `while` so you'll short circuit.

`valgrind` (or Clang's address sanitizer) can help catch both of these issues if you're on a Linux system.

Comment: It was the `inputCopy` that was leading to the problem. Stephen got it first, Charles has written a clearer answer (as well covering another weakness that would also surface). So if you wanna expand your answer you get the approved one, else it goes to Charles :)

Comment: I switch tabs and find out I'm under the gun. Might be the most exciting question I've participated in on Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to check `j < size` first, and *strengthen* it to `j + 1 < size` else you run the risk of an out-of-bounds array access, which is undefined behaviour:

```
while (j + 1 < size && inputCopy[j] == inputCopy[j + 1]){
```

(The right hand argument of `&&` is only evaluated if `j + 1 < size` is 1.)

And where is the memory allocated for `inputCopy`?

Answer (score 3):

Here you define `test` as an array of length 10:

```
char test[10] = "aaaaaaasdd";
```

Then you pass it to `compress` with 10 as the `size`:

```
printf("%s \n", compress(test, 10));
```

This conditional will remain true while `i` is 0 through 9:

```
while(i < size){
```

And same for `j`:

```
j = i;
```

And when `j` is equal to 9, this line will try to access element `j + 1`, which is 10, of your array, which is out of bounds:

```
while (inputCopy[j] == inputCopy[j + 1] && j < size){
```

This will cause undefined behavior. Most likely this is the source of your crash, and the thing with `counter` is incidental.

**EDIT:** Aaaaaand you're also not allocating any memory for `inputCopy` on this line, which will also lead to undefined behavior:

```
snprintf(inputCopy, size, "%s", input);
```

Answer (score 2):

It is illegal to write to `inputCopy`. It points to random memory:

```
char *inputCopy;
char compressedString[100];
snprintf(inputCopy, size, "%s", input); // !? memory not allocated for the inputCopy
```